# Не выходит залить файл на ftp сервер

Tags: android, сервер, ftp, клиент-сервер

Пытаюсь залить файл с android вот код загрузки

```
 public boolean ftpUpload(String localFilePath, String serverFilePath)
{
    boolean status = false;
    if (mFTPClient.isConnected())
    {
        try
        {
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/Kate.apk");
            Log.d("myLog", sdPath.getPath() + "in");
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sdPath);
            status = mFTPClient.storeFile(serverFilePath, in);

            in.close();

            return status;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("myLog", "upload failed: " + e);
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

А вот что мне выдает ftp сервер

```
Jul 24 23:36:00 vsftpd[9498]: [EductUsers] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.1.100"
Jul 24 23:36:00 vsftpd[9500]: [EductUsers] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "192.168.1.100", "/Server/Educt/Kate.apk", 0.00Kbyte/sec
```

Comment: права на чтение есть?

Comment: @metalurgus и на чтение и на запись и на интернет есть